# Spring MVC <form:errors/> tag doesn't find error messages, what do I wrong?

Tags: java, jsp, annotations

I use following in my index.jsp file:

```
<form:label path="userName">User name</form><form:input path="userName"/><form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error"/>
```

My entity file looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

@Column(name = "username")
@NotNull(message = "User name is required.")
@NotBlank(message = "User name can't be left blank.")
private String userName;

...
```

When I left all fields blank and I push the save user button, I recieve a http 500 error, with following message:

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested    exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes  [be.fgov.economie.Spring3Hibernate4.entity.User] during persist time for groups  [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='User name can't be left blank.', propertyPath=userName, rootBeanClass=class be.fgov.economie.Spring3Hibernate4.entity.User, messageTemplate='User name can't be left blank.'}
]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:932)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

So I see that it works, but I do not get the message with the form:errors tag. What do I wrong or did I forgot something?

Thx

Comment: Judging from the stacktrace it fails while saving/persisting to the database and not while submitting the form. Assuming you are using Spring MVC you should annotate the method parameter with `@Valid`.

Comment: Yes, that was what I forgot. I just added following to my controller class: public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model) { if(result.hasErrors()) { return "index"; } ... } And it works fine now, thx.